# R: Filtering and mutating a data frame WITH replacement

Tags: r, dplyr

I am attempting to select all TRUE values that are above 3.0 and replace the TF column too FALSE. I can do this but am having trouble replacing it in the original data frame. Suggestions?

```
df <- data.frame("TF" = c("TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE"),
                 "Number" = c(4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.5, 3.0, 1.0))


df %>%
  filter(TF == TRUE) %>%
  filter(Number <= 3) %>%
  mutate(TF = FALSE)
```

The final data frame should be:

"TF" = c("TRUE", "FALSE", **"FALSE"**, **"FALSE"**, "FALSE", "FALSE")

"Number" = c(4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.5, 3.0, 1.0)

Comment: Which trouble you had?

Comment: You don't really want to `filter` twice then `mutate`, you want to `mutate` the TF column based upon some `ifelse` logic.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

`df%>%
 mutate(TF = as.logical(TF))%>%
 mutate(TF = ifelse(TF & Number <= 3.0, F, TF)`.

Answer (score 1):

Base R may be your better bet here

```
df[df$TF & df$Number <= 3, "TF"] <- FALSE
```

If you're really set on tidyverse

```
mutate(df, TF = if_else(TF & (Number <=3), FALSE, TF))
```

Comment: I would prefer to use Tidyverse as the rest of my code is using it but the example above doesn't seem to be working for me. (error: & not meaningful for factors)

Comment: Your "TRUE is not a `TRUE` which is what Marcus is relying on.

Comment: In your definition of `df` don't quote TRUE and FALSE. `data.frame` is reading these as strings, and if you're using R version before 4.0, it converts these to factors.

Comment: Yes I am running R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29), I will change to logical

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)


df <- data.frame("TF" = c("TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE"),
                 "Number" = c(4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.5, 3.0, 1.0))


df <- df %>%
  mutate(TF = as.character(TF)) %>%
  mutate(TF = if_else(TF == "TRUE" & Number <= 3, "FALSE", TF))

df

df
#>      TF Number
#> 1  TRUE    4.0
#> 2 FALSE    4.0
#> 3 FALSE    3.0
#> 4 FALSE    2.5
#> 5 FALSE    3.0
#> 6 FALSE    1.0
```

Comment: When I run it, I get this response: Error: `false` must be a character vector, not a `factor` object

Comment: I edited it but it means your sample isn't quite what you say it is.